# ArrayAdapter constantly raising errors with spinner

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

My code:

```
public class SpeedZonesFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener {


    Spinner spinner;


... // Declaring onCreate and so on

    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.chosen_zone);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(MainActivity.this, R.array.speed_zones, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() // the program continues
```

Raises the error:
`No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope`

I know why it does this but not how to fix it.
I have the `MainActivity` which does nothing but handle tabs a ViewPager.

I have tried to use `.createFromResource` with no luck.

I know the solution might be basic but after a few hours of browsing for solutions and trying different approaches to implement the `OnItemSelectedListener` i simply can't find the answer. What am i missing for either scoping `MainActivity` or implementing the adapter differently (in order to get the `Listener` to work)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `MainActivity.this`, you can do `getActivity()` in your fragment.